# How to debug a rails (3.2) app started by foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, foreman

I am trying to use foreman to start my rails app. Unfortunately I have difficulties connecting my IDE for debugging.

I read [here](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/58) about using

```
Debugger.wait_connection = true
Debugger.start_remote
```

to start a remote debugging session, but that does not really work out.

**Question:**
Is there a way to debug a rails (3.2) app started by foreman? If so, what is the approach?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you use several workers with full rails environment you could use the following initializer:

```
# Enabled debugger with foreman, see https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/58
if Rails.env.development?
  require 'debugger'
  Debugger.wait_connection = true

  def find_available_port
    server = TCPServer.new(nil, 0)
    server.addr[1]
  ensure
    server.close if server
  end

  port = find_available_port
  puts "Remote debugger on port #{port}"
  Debugger.start_remote(nil, port)
end
```

And in the foreman's logs you'll be able to find debugger's ports:

```
$ foreman start
12:48:42 web.1     | started with pid 29916
12:48:42 worker.1  | started with pid 29921
12:48:44 web.1     | I, [2012-10-30T12:48:44.810464 #29916]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:5000 fd=10
12:48:44 web.1     | I, [2012-10-30T12:48:44.810636 #29916]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
12:48:47 web.1     | Remote debugger on port 59269
12:48:48 worker.1  | Remote debugger on port 41301
```

Now run debugger using:

```
rdebug -c -p [PORT]
```

Comment: Clearly, you need more upvotes. Thanks to you, I *finally* got this to work. Thanks!

Comment: For completeness, the final step is to connect to the debugger in a separate shell with `rails -c -p  [PORT]`

Comment: @Philipp - Did you mean ```rdebug -c -p [PORT]```?  Using the ```rails``` command did not work for me.

Comment: @Tim, sorry about that -- yes, it should be `rdebug`.

Comment: so, I have this working, however my debugger process gets killed every 30 seconds as I'm using Unicorn server and `timeout 30` in my unicorn.rb config file. i have tried several solutions to change the timeout if i'm in the development environment but it doesn't work. here's the code i'm trying:  `if ENV['development'] timeout 300 else timeout 30 end`. Any ideas how to get this to work on Unicorn/Foreman without it timing out only in dev env? thanks! i upvoted

Comment: I solved the Unicorn timeout using `Rails.env.development?` instead of `ENV['development']`

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to require debugger normally in your gemfile, and add `debugger` normally in your code as needed. When the server hits that line, it will stop, but foreman won't be verbose about it. In your foreman console you can *blindly* type `irb`, and only then will you see a prompt appear. Bad UX, right?

Another (augmentative) approach is to tail your logs:

```
tail -f log/development.log
```

Hope this helps.