# When using Foreman with Rails 4 and a debug listener locally there is no response from the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, foreman

I want to use Foreman for local development however I also want to be able to debug my code. In order to make this happen I've used this initializer:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  require 'debugger'
  Debugger.wait_connection = true

  def find_available_port
    server = TCPServer.new(nil, 0)
    server.addr[1]
  ensure
    server.close if server
  end

  port = find_available_port
  puts "Remote debugger on port #{port}"
  Debugger.start_remote(nil, port)
end
```

as recommended here: [How to debug a rails (3.2) app started by foreman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558576/how-to-debug-a-rails-3-2-app-started-by-foreman). However, when I start foreman the browser can't seem to find anything on port 5000:

```
$ foreman start
09:48:18 web.1  | started with pid 25337
09:48:23 web.1  | => Booting Thin
09:48:23 web.1  | => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:5000
09:48:23 web.1  | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
09:48:23 web.1  | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
09:48:23 web.1  | Remote debugger on port 57466
```

If I go to 0.0.0.0:5000 I see:

=> `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 0.0.0.0:5000`

Comment: Same problem, any news?

Comment: @woohoou nothing unfortunately. I've just been working around it

Comment: @woohoou - just added an answer which partially addresses this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a less than ideal solution, however...

It is possible to use the debugger with Foreman and *without* any initializer. Simply insert a debugger statement in your code as you would normally and you will see that the execution will stop.

Your terminal window will print out the last few lines of execution as normal and will look something like this:

```
11:23:57 web.1  |   Rendered editor/memberships/_memberships.html.haml (76.6ms)
11:23:57 web.1  |   Rendered editor/memberships/_memberships.html.haml (0.2ms)
11:23:57 web.1  | /rails/yourapp/yourapp-code/app/views/editor/memberships/_form.html.haml:2
11:23:57 web.1  | = simple_form_for membership, url: membership.path(:create_or_update) do |f|
11:23:57 web.1  | [-3, 6] in /rails/yourapp/yourapp-code/app/views/editor/memberships/_form.html.haml
11:23:57 web.1  |    1  - debugger
11:23:57 web.1  | => 2  = simple_form_for membership, url: membership.path(:create_or_update) do |f|
11:23:57 web.1  |    3    = f.fields_for :member do |u_f|
11:23:57 web.1  |    4      = u_f.input :email, placeholder: "Enter their email address", label: 'Invite a new administrator'
11:23:57 web.1  |    5    = f.submit 'Add admin', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-success'    
11:23:57 web.1  | (rdb:1) membership
11:23:57 web.1  | #<MembershipDecorator:0x007fb03fee1168 @object=#<Membership id: nil, org_id: 1, member_id: nil, role: "basic", active: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @context={}>
11:24:02 web.1  | (rdb:1) membership
11:24:02 web.1  | #<MembershipDecorator:0x007fb03fee1168 @object=#<Membership id: nil, org_id: 1, member_id: nil, role: "basic", active: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @context={}>
```

#### Even though there's no prompt the debugger has nonetheless started

At this point there is no prompt and if you type anything it doesn't come up on screen. However it will get executed when you press return and the output will display in the terminal.

So the trick is that the debugger has started and you can use it and see its output, you just can't see what you're typing. I've no idea how to fix this but at least you can continue debugging.