# How do I run Heroku foreman in debug mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, heroku, foreman

I'd like to start Heroku's `foreman` like I can start `rails server` in debug mode.  In other words, what's the `foreman` equivalent of:

```
rails server --debugger
```

EDIT: I'm using Ruby on Rails 4 and `foreman` 0.60.0

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558576/how-to-debug-a-rails-3-2-app-started-by-foreman

Comment: @diego Thanks.  That's still not an ideal solution however since it requires I insert code into my initializer and is not easily toggled on and off.

Comment: It could very well be easy to toggle by using environment vars