# Is there a reliable tool for stepping through code while serving in foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, foreman, pry

I'm looking for some suggestions on a tool similar to using binding.pry.

I'm serving a rails app locally with foreman and would like to accomplish the same ability to put "debuggers" in my code and when the process hits that, freeze and open a console environment in that section of the code.

I've tried using pry with foreman to no avail and was curious if there are other known tools I'm not finding through google?

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I think here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558576/how-to-debug-a-rails-3-2-app-started-by-foreman

Comment: Thank you I've already seen this post.

Answer (score 3):

Try [pry-remote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote), it seems to be the answer of running Pry with Foreman.

Checklist:

1. Make sure you're using `binding.remote_pry` instead of `binding.pry`.
2. Make sure to run your program making binding.remote_pry first and then run in console `remote-pry`, otherwise the pry server won't be running.
3. If nothing helps, try adding `require 'pry-remote'` at the top of your `.rb` file.
4. Check also this [issue](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote/issues/8).

Comment: Cannot use the same IP address for both foreman and pry remote

Comment: Could you elaborate on that in your question? Do you get any error message? What's your setup?

Comment: Sure, so I'm using foreman to serve up my website and 3 unicorn workers which are running on localhost port 5000 pry is throwing the following error: rescue in block in open': druby://127.0.0.1:9876 - #<Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9876> - - this is in the command line while in the app the following error reads: Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 9876

Comment: I should also note ruby v 2.1.3 and rails 4

Comment: Did you use `binding.remote_pry` instead of `binding.pry`?

Comment: yes, I did. I've simply decided not to use foreman in development and to just use rails server instead.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue, please look at my post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780971/pry-remote-not-triggered-rails-4