# How do I start Rails with foreman on a dedicated debug port with Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4, foreman, ruby-debug-ide

I’m using Rails 4.2.  I start Rails using foreman, and I would like to attach a debugger when starting Rails.  This question details the process for Rails 3.2 — [How to debug a rails (3.2) app started by foreman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558576/how-to-debug-a-rails-3-2-app-started-by-foreman), however I believe this file is outdated

```
$ cat config/initializers/start_debugger.rb
# Enabled debugger with foreman, see https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/58
if Rails.env.development?
  require 'debugger'
  Debugger.wait_connection = true

  def find_available_port
    server = TCPServer.new(nil, 0)
    server.addr[1]
  ensure
    server.close if server
  end

  port = find_available_port
  puts "Remote debugger on port #{port}"
  Debugger.start_remote(nil, port)
end
```

Since I don’t think the “debugger” gem is supported by Rails 4.2.  How would I start Rails using foreman on a dedicated debug port using Rails 4.2?

Comment: have you tried byebug? https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md#debugging-remote-programs

Comment: I'd be open to this, but the link doesn't talk about how I would integrate this so that I could start Rails via foreman and enable the debug port.  Starting Rails via foreman is a requirement of our project.

Answer (score 1):

based on your comment, you said that you open to use byebug
so this is the guide to set it up for Foreman

edit config/environments/development.rb

```
require "byebug/core"
port = ENV['DEBUGGER_PORT'] # any port that you like
Byebug.wait_connection = true
Byebug.start_server("localhost", port)
```

let say you would like to debug your controller

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

and you want to see `@posts` value
then just add byebug after the `@posts`

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  byebug
end
```

and do request to your #index endpoint
rails server will be paused on `byebug` line
you need to execute `byebug -R localhost:8899` in another terminal

---

if you see this one https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/lib/byebug/remote/server.rb#L30 . it uses TCPServer too. so it's similar to your own implementation.

your foreman setting can read ENV['DEBUGGER_PORT'] too

Comment: Thanks, but again this doesn't tell me how to expose a debug port when Rails starts with foreman.  Also I intend to debug using VSCode extensions and would prefer not to add code into Rails specifically for debugging, as I understand VS Code would allow me to set breakpoints and debug directly in the IDE

Comment: see my updated post